# What is the difference between there has `(config-if)` and not in Cisco IOS?

Tags: networking, switch

What is the difference between there has `(config-if)` and not in Cisco IOS?

[image: (config-if) explaination]

Above is a snapshot of a Cisco 2960 Switch. I don't know what's the meaning of the `(config-if)` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(config-if)` simply means you're in "Interface Configuration" mode, i.e. you did something like

```
Central(config)#interface Gi0/1
Central(config-if)#interface Gi0/1
```

while in "Global Configuration Mode" (i.e. the simple `(config)`).

Answer (score 1):

That's mean it is under the configure mode, and configuring a interface.

in your scenario, you type `configure`, it will enter configure mode.

it will become:

```
Central(config)#
```

if again enter `interface FastEthernet0/1`, it will become:

```
Central(config-if)#
```